# Convertir datetime "DD/MM/YYYY" a un string "YYMMDD" en C#

Tags: c#, datetime, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo el valor de una fecha en un `DateEdit` el cual el valor por defecto es `DD/MM/YYYY` y necesito convertirlo a un `string` con formato `YYMMDD` para mostrarlo en un `TextBox` ya que va a definir el nombre de una tarea en esa fecha.

Tengo este código usando el método `ParseExact()`:

```
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(edtStartDate.Text, new[] { "YYYYMMDD", "YYMMDD" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None );
tbSubject.Text = fecha.ToString("YYMMDD");
```

Pero lanza una excepción de que no lo reconoce como un `string` válido y no encuentro qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los operadores `ToString()` de los `DateTime` los puedes encontrar en [esta página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

El problema que tienes, es que estás poniendo mal el texto en el `ToString()`.

Si te fijas en la página que te he proporcionado, los días se indican con `d` minúscula, los meses se indican con la `M` mayúscula, pero de nuevo, los años se indican con la `y` minúscula.

Prueba en modificar esas partes y a ver si se te soluciona el error.

Comment: Perfecto Marc, me funcionó con el ejemplo que me pasaste. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que quieres el formato en AñoMesDía (yyyyMMdd) sería solamente convertir la fecha con un `ToString()` de la siguiente forma: `fecha.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`; eso ya lo explico el colega `Marc` en la respuesta anterior.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Paulo, lo solucioné con el link de la respuesta de Marc

Answer (score 0):

```
string Date = "20190920";
string day = String.Format("{0:dd}", DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
string month = String.Format("{0:MM}", DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
string year = String.Format("{0:yyyy}", DateTime.ParseExact(Date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como funciona el sitio y así de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para formular una respuesta de calidad y que esta sea bien recibida. Quizá una breve descripción ayude a entender lo que haces o incluso explicar por que ocurre y como lo arreglas.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos agregar una explicaciòn del còdigo