# String.Format("dd/MM/yyyy") guiones en vez de barras en C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

tengo esta consulta Linq en c#:

```
var consulta = objeto.Select(el => new 
            {
                Nombre = el.Nombre,
                Descripcion = el.Descripcion,
                Fecha = el.Fecha?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
            });
```

y en vez de recibir "05/10/2021" recibo "05-10-2021", o sea no me respeta las barras. Que estaria pasando?
Puede tener algo que ver el Nulleable?

Comment: ¿Qué opciones tienes en el sistema con respecto a Region y Cultura?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir datetime "DD/MM/YYYY" a un string "YYMMDD" en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93870/convertir-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-a-un-string-yymmdd-en-c)

Comment: @fredyfx sospeche que podia ser por eso pero me gustaria que de forma independiente del regional siempre aparezcan con /. Me he dado cuenta que si pongo "dd MM yyyy" sale sin nada, como podria concatenar una barra en medio? Intente con "dd \/ MM \/ yyyy" pero me da error

Comment: ya resolvi como @"dd\/MM\/yyyy"